# Trouble with aligning two y-axis ticks with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to align two sets of separate y-axis using python and matplotlib, and am running into behavior I don't understand. Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot 
import numpy as np

fig = mplot.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(1, 4, 1)
s1 = np.exp(t)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()    
ax1.semilogx(t, s1)
ax2.set_yticks(2*ax1.get_yticks())
mplot.show()
```

This produces the expected result (from http://postimg.org/image/qowrjnnr5/):
[image: good result]

however, changing the definition of t to

```
t = np.arrange(1, 3, 1)
```

produces the result (http://postimg.org/image/swanojt0b):

[image: bad result]

where you can see that the y axis ticks on the right side are off-shifted.

What am I missing in order to prevent this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two y axes do not have the same limits: in one case you fluke the same lower value in the automatic range calculation while in the other you don't.  If you define one yaxis range in terms of the other,  I think you achieve what you want:

```
lim1 = ax1.get_ylim()
lim2 = (lim1[0]*2, lim1[1] *2)
ax2.set_ylim(lim2)
```

(and if you don't explicitly set the ax2 yticks then ticks will still get rendered if you move beyond the original range in interactive mode).

[image: y tick positions corresponding on each side]