# matplotlib: Aligning twin y-axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944139/trouble-with-aligning-two-y-axis-ticks-with-matplotlib) suggests that I play around with the `set_ylim`/`get_ylim` in order to align two twin axes. However, this does not seem to be working out for me.

Code snippet:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

yLim = [minY, maxY]
xLim = [0, 0.01]

for x in analysisNumbers:
    ax1.plot(getData(x), vCoords, **getStyle(x))

ax1.set_yticks(vCoords)
ax1.grid(True, which='major')


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(ax1.get_yticks())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

plt.xlim(xLim[0], xLim[1])
plt.ylim(yLim[0], yLim[1])

plt.minorticks_on()

plt.show()
```

Graph output (open image in a new window):

[image]

The twin axes should be the same, but they are not. Their labels are the same, but their alignment is not (see that the zeroes do not line up). What's wrong?

Comment: please show the rest of your code (omit the plotting commands if necessary). you're clearly manipulating the axes in more than the 5 lines shown.

Comment: @PaulH I have put in the rest of the relevant matplot lib code, as requested.

Comment: The problem is the `plt.ylim` line which applies to only the current axes, hence they are not lined up because you instructed the library to have them not lined up.

Comment: @tcaswell So I should set up the axes to have the limits set to them manually? How would I do that?

Comment: @tcaswell I figured out how to set the axis limits without using `plt.ylim` (instead used `ax1.set_ylim`, for example), and that did indeed solve my problems. Could you write up an answer so that I could give you some internet points?

Comment: Write up your own answer

Comment: @tcaswell Suit yourself.

Comment: Sorry, that came out more terse than I intended. You should write an answer to your own question so you get internet points for your work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858192/how-to-set-xlim-and-ylim-for-a-subplot-in-matplotlib/15858264#15858264

Answer (score 1):

As tcaswell points out in a comment, `plt.ylim()` only affects one of the axes. If you replace these lines:

```
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

plt.xlim(xLim[0], xLim[1])
plt.ylim(yLim[0], yLim[1])
```

with this:

```
ax1.set_ylim(yLim[0], yLim[1])
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())

plt.xlim(xLim[0], xLim[1])
```

It'll work as I'm guessing you intended.